# How to set up a percentage using generate + variable conditions?

Tags: stata

I've been working in Stata on data visualization specifically visualizing a sideways histogram. My percentage is based on 2 variables: one variable is Female Members in Village Leadership (Boolean) which is composed of 2 other variables, being gender (Boolean) and village membership (Boolean) and their response on a survey about weather patterns (scaled; 1-5 1 = strongly agree and 5 = strongly disagree).

What I've been trying to do is find the percentage of female village leaders who agree with the survey's statements. When I compile the line and look at my data table I see the variable just giving me 0s. The answer should be 100% or 1 since I've tabulated both variables ahead of time and know that every female in village leadership agrees with the survey statement.
What would be the correct way to create this percentage?

Or a another question, how should I go about creating a percentage from what I've shared? I should also note that I want this in a bar graph and that bar graph should be made with percentile in mind.

Here's code I've tried

```
gen F_GP_WPAgree = F_GP_Member == 2 & Weather_Pattern_N < 3/13

gen F_GP_WPAgree = F_GP_Member == 2 & Weather_Pattern_N < 3/F_GP_Member

gen F_GP_WPAgree = F_GP_Member == 2 & Weather_Pattern_N < 3/F_GP_Member == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The Boolean variable `F_GP_WPAgree` should ideally capture whether each individual is both a female village leader (`F_GP_Member == 2`) and in agreement with the survey (`Weather_Pattern_N < 3`).

```
gen F_GP_WPAgree = (F_GP_Member == 2 & Weather_Pattern_N < 3)
```

Following the generation of this new variable, you then focus on summarizing the information specifically for female village leaders:

```
summarize F_GP_WPAgree if F_GP_Member == 2
```

This will provide you with a mean value for `F_GP_WPAgree` for your subset of female village leaders. If the mean is 1, it signifies full agreement among them with the survey statement, as per expectations.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the feedback! What I decided to do was create an if condition when I generated my variable. The code I wrote `gen F_GP_WPAgree = 1 if F_GP_Member == 2 & Weather_Pattern_N < 3`. I should've put this in the post originally, but the bar graph should be done in percetile, not mean. So, given that information what else should I do? When I do `F_GP_WPAgreeP = F_GP_WPAgree/F_GP_Member` I get 0.5 which isnt the answer.

Comment: Ok, then you can do this:

`F_GP_WPAgree = 1 if F_GP_Member == 2 & Weather_Pattern_N < 3`

And then:

`egen total_females = total(F_GP_Member == 2)`

`egen agreeing_females = total(F_GP_WPAgree == 1)`

`gen percentile_F_GP_WPAgree = agreeing_females / total_females`